# custom pagination, arrows instead of Next Previous

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I want to extend the default pagination to use buttons with arrows or images instead of `Next` `Previous` text links.

On script initialization I tried to use

```
    ...
     "oPaginate": {                       
             "sNext": '<i class="entypo-right-circled" ></i>',
             "sPrevious": '<i class="entypo-left-circled" class="Dia_pagination_ico" ></i>'
     },
    ...
```

but I still have default pagination like

[image]

Comment: So, whats before and after `...` ?? It is a little bit weird that we are only allowed to see what content you want to replace the default content with - but _how_ and _where_ you are trying to do it (and by that the possibility to spot out where and how you are doing it wrong) - that remains a mystery :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can customize the pagination button labels through [`language.paginate.next`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate.next) and [`language.paginate.previous`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.paginate.previous).

```
$('#the_table').DataTable({
  language: {
    paginate: {
      next: '&#8594;', // or '→'
      previous: '&#8592;' // or '←' 
    }
  }
});
```

Because the values for `next` and `previous` can include markup, you can even use an image or a glyph icon font.

```
$('#the_table').DataTable({
  language: {
    paginate: {
      next: '<img src="path/to/arrow.png">',
      previous: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-long-arrow-left">'  
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to include an arrow before or after the existing text, you can also use plain CSS:

```
.paginate_button.previous:before {
  content: '← ';
}

.paginate_button.next:after {
  content: ' →';
}
```